# How can I get connection with Raspberry without access of its shell?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

There are Raspberry Pi 3 model B and MicroSD with NOOBS OS. Unfortunately I have not any display to get a direct access to NOOBS shell. So remote connection could be set via ssh. However my device does not have any IP-address. I read everywhere that the connection options must be set... via shell. But it's impossible for me! 
How can I resolve this problem and get remote access to shell (or to desktop even)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this a while ago, I started using [PiBakery](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiBsLvD6-fQAhUIllQKHcy4CiIQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pibakery.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNFbekrTnwPc93vKfcCLs0fBrdTRsw&sig2=Q1chlBMboU5BL9uTq1EZoA&bvm=bv.141320020,d.cGw). It will write raspbian to the SD card and add a startup script to connect to the network and enable ssh. This way the first time you boot it up, its ready to go and you can connect via SSH.

When you set it up, it also allows you to set a static IP address so you know exactly where it is when it boots.

Answer (score 1):

Enable SSH by placing a file named 'ssh', without any extension, onto the boot partition of the SD card.

Connect your device to your LAN using a wired connection.

From another computer on the network execute `arp -a` to view locally connected hosts and get your raspberry pi's  IP address.

From there you should be able to SSH into your pi.