# Can not SSH to Raspberry Pi 3 from Putty

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I am not able to SSH to Raspberry Pi 3 from Putty. I can ping the 192.168.137.1 IP address assigned by sharing Internet connection.

The problem I realized that SSH is not enabled by default in Pi3 and saw the posts which suggest to enable SSH by creating 'ssh' file inside /boot folder. I got the SD card which has pre-installed Noobs so when I open SD card it shows only /recovery folder. How to enable SSH in this case ? Please help to resolve it .

Answer (score 0):

Enable SSH like:
[documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/)
Or start it manually `sudo service ssh start` - note that  manual option will require startup scrip to run at each startup.
Additional settings like port configuration should be done in`sshd_config`. Do it with your favorite editor `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Anyway your post should be opened at raspberry forum not at SO...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do not have monitor to connect HDMI cable to access its screen. So i do not have any option to access pi3 apart from SSH ? Is there any idea ?

Comment: Blindly. Plug in your keyboard to Pi3, boot up. wait some time, press `Ctrl + Alt + F1` to open terminal. type in: `sudo service ssh start`, confirm with password `raspberry`. Try to SHH on port 22

Comment: But unfortunately, it did not work. I am not sure about the timing when to press Ctrl+Alt+F1. I did after waiting for some time, but does not work.  Now,
I got monitor with HDMI display but it seems i need to adjust the size from /boot/config.txt file. Is it ? If so, i am again running into problem of not having /boot folder. The error I am getting while connecting HDMI to raspberry pi3 is "change screen resolution to 1920*1080, the display setting not supported" message. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at this thread

[How can I get connection with Raspberry without access of its shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067489/how-can-i-get-connection-with-raspberry-without-access-of-its-shell?rq=1)

it mentions about PiBakery which will install rasbian with ssh support. by default ssh is disabled but this might help.

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon because links can become broken. Please try to summarize the relevant portions of what is found within the link here. The user can go to that link for more information if need be.